# Python remove dictionary in a list by key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Consider the following code:

```
some_list = [
    {'id' : '3459', 'name' : 'Alice'},
    {'id' : '1112', 'name': 'Bob'}
]
person_id = '3459'
# Search person id in list of dictionaries and return {'id' : '3459', 'name' : 'Alice'}
```

Knowing the `person_id`, is it possible to search this `some_list` by `'id'` to grab the whole dictionary? Currently I am doing this with a for loop, but I was curious if there was any other implementations. Thanks to all of those who reply.

Comment: nope, since it's a list, you've lost the ability of quick lookups that a dict offers. some form of iteration is needed now, unless you use a dict instead of a list.

Comment: yes you'd be better off refactoring `some_list` into something like a dict with key id and value name

Comment: @Chris_Rands do you possibly have a quick implementation of this?

Comment: Assuming no duplicate ids: `{d['id']: d['name'] for d in some_list}`

Comment: @Chris_Rands what does `d` refer to?

Comment: did you try it? each dictionary within `some_list` like `for d in some_list:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can transform the structure to a nested dictionary, where the key is `id`. Then you maintain constant **O(1)** lookups, instead of scanning the list in linear **O(N)** time.

**Example:**

```
data = {
    '3459': {
        'name' : 'Alice'
    },
    '1112': {
        'name': 'Bob'
    }
}

person_id = '3459'

print(data[person_id])
# {'name': 'Alice'}
```

You could also just have `name` as a value instead of a dictionary:

```
data = {
    '3459': 'Alice',
    '1112': 'Bob'
}

person_id = '3459'

print(data[person_id])
# Alice
```

**Note:** This assumes no duplicate ids, as [@Chris_Rands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57220041/python-remove-dictionary-in-a-list-by-key/57220183#comment100944603_57220183) mentioned in the comments

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
[entry for entry in some_list if person_id in entry['id']]
```

If you want the result not to be a list, try this:

```
[entry for entry in some_list if person_id in entry['id']][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import time
start = time.time() 

person_id = '3459'
some_list = [
    {'id' : '3459', 'name' : 'Alice'},
    {'id' : '1112', 'name': 'Bob'}
]

a = pd.DataFrame(some_list) 
a.drop(a.loc[a['id']==person_id].index, inplace=True)
end = time.time()
print(a)
print(end - start)
```

output

```
     id name
1  1112  Bob
0.0030059814453125
```

Comment: How does the running time of this implementation compare to the solution RoadRunner suggested?

Comment: @KyleDeGennaro I updated answer. Pandas has c++ under the hood and it's very fast way. Believe me :)

Comment: it will still be iteration, since you're going through a list, so the longer the structure the longer your code takes. RoadRunner's solution is a workaround to avoid using lists and thus has the same speed regardless of the size of data.

Comment: @RedaDrissi yep it slower than O(1) when you find by key in dict. But faster than finding in list

Comment: RoadRunners solution is not using lists. Your solution will have at best O(n) worst-case complexity, because you have to iterate manually through every element, you mentionned pandas uses c++ code, maybe that's why it's faster than iterating through the list in python.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
some_list = [
{'id' : '3459', 'name' : 'Alice'},
{'id' : '1112', 'name': 'Bob'}
]

person_id = '3459'

result = list(filter(lambda x : x['id'] == person_id, 
some_list))

print(result)
```